# Ember Selection Box undefined on observe

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember selection box as follows:

```
 {{view "select" class="form-control" content=chooseChannel
                        optionLabelPath="content.name"
                        optionValuePath="content.value"
                        value=selectedChannel                            
                        prompt="Please Select"
 }}
```

And a function as follows:

```
  watchtype:function(){           
    console.log(this.get("selectedChannel"));    
}.observes('selectedChannel'),
```

So, The function gets triggered everytime the user selects a value in the selection box.

My problem is that the function returns undefined even though it is triggered from the change of value of the the variable.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: can u throw this up into a jsbin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered what's wrong. The JSON I'm retrieving from the server didn't have a "value" field to bind to. So when I bound the value optionValuePath to content.name, it worked.